# What it is the best general way for testing overflow in Long operations?

Tags: android, kotlin, entity-relationship

In *Kotlin*, as in *Java*, there is no **overflow error** in arithmetic operations. I know that there are special *Java* operations that test *overflow* and throw exceptions that need to be handled.

I would want a simpler way. So I thought of a model, which is not so efficient, but it is very simple and effective.

Suppose someone wants to test a 2 long numbers multiplication: `a * b`

I use

```
if ( a.doDouble()* b.toDouble()  - a*b != 0.0 )
   println("Overflow")
else
   println("Ok")
```

The justification is simple. Within the universe of `Long` the difference between a number and its `Double` is always `0`, even at extreme values, when the `Double` does not reach all precision. In this case, adding or subtracting a small number does not even change the equality test:.

```
   var l1= -Long.MAX_VALUE
   var d1 = l1.toDouble()
   if (d1-l1==0.0) println("-MaxLong")
   if (d1+100-l1==0.0) println("it still -MaxLong")
   var l2= Long.MAX_VALUE
   var d2 =l2.toDouble()
   if (d2-l2==0.0) println("MaxLong")
   if (d2+100-l2==0.0) println("it still MaxLong")
```

This generates the output:

```
-MaxLong
it still -MaxLong
MaxLong
it still MaxLong
```

Is it correct or I'm missing something? 
Even if it's correct, is there any other solution better than this?

**Update 1**: Notice that other  possibility  is testing if `Double` calculation is greater that `longValue.MAXVALUE`. However, it fails!

```
   var n1= Long.MAX_VALUE/2+1 
   var n2= Long.MAX_VALUE/2+1
   println((n1.toDouble()+n2.toDouble()) - 
         Long.MAX_VALUE.toDouble()==0.0)
   println((n1.toDouble()+n2.toDouble()) > Long.MAX_VALUE.toDouble())
```

It prints:

```
true
false
```

**Update 2**: Although my solution seems to work, it doesn't!
[Alexey Romanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9204/alexey-romanov), points me in his accepted answer the following situation:

```
  val lo1 = Long.MAX_VALUE - 600
  val lo2 = 100L
  var do1: Double = lo1.toDouble()
  var do2:Double = lo2.toDouble()
  var d= do1+do2
  var l=lo1+lo2  
  println(d-l==0.0)
```

As the result is inside `Long` range, it should gives `true`, but it gives `false`, because `Double` calculation is not exact!

As he said, the best way is really using special functions like `multiplyExact` encapsulated in an user function.

Unfortunately, its resources only can be used in `Android` from API 24 onwards, so it rests the other solution from [Alexey Romanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9204/alexey-romanov), that consists in test the inverse operation.

So, for instance, in the multiplication one should do:

```
   var a = Long.MIN_VALUE 
   var b = -1L
   var c = a*b
   if (b!=0 && c/b != a) 
    println("overflow $c")
   else
    println("ok $c")
```

It prints `overflow -9223372036854775808`

Among traditional operations, there are usually concerns with *addition*, *subtraction*, and *multiplication*, which are the object of the functions `addExact`, `subtractExact`, `multipyExact` functions, that are easily emulated using inverse operations, as cited.

*Negation* (`inv()`) also has the `negateExact` function to deal with the negation of `Long.MIN_VALUE`, which is invalid as it has no positive counterpart. Less commented is the *division*, which has no specialized function in Java to lead with overflow. However it gives problem in a single case: `Long.MIN_VALUE / -1` is invalid.

Comment: Perhaps use [`Math.multiplyExact`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java#l872)

Comment: Yes, I know it, but I would not want to throw an exception. I would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Within the universe of Long the difference between a number and its Double is always 0

No, not really.

```
println(Long.MAX_VALUE)
println(BigDecimal(Long.MAX_VALUE.toDouble()))
```

prints

```
9223372036854775807
9223372036854775808
```

You tried to check this:

```
var l2= Long.MAX_VALUE
var d2 =l2.toDouble()
if (d2-l2==0.0) println("MaxLong")
```

But the problem is that arithmetic operations on JVM (and in most languages, really) can only work on values of the same type, so the compiler inserts `toDouble()` and you really calculate `d2 - l2.toDouble()`.

If you want a simple test, you can do

```
val product = a*b
if ((b != 0 && product/b != a) || (a == Long.MIN_VALUE && b == -1)) {
    println("Overflow")
} else {
    // can use product here
    println("OK")
}
```

but really, using `multiplyExact` instead of doing it manually makes more sense. Or use Kotlin's nullable types and define

```
fun multiplyExact(x: Long, y: Long): Long? = 
    try { java.math.multiplyExact(x, y) } catch (e: ArithmeticException) { null }
```

EDIT: to demonstrate a fault in your test, consider addition (I am pretty sure it's wrong for multiplication as well, but it's harder to find suitable numbers):

```
val largeNumber = Long.MAX_VALUE - 600
val smallNumber = 100L
// prints true, even though there's no overflow
println((largeNumber.toDouble() + smallNumber.toDouble()) - (largeNumber + smallNumber) != 0.0)
```

The reason is that `largeNumber.toDouble() + smallNumber.toDouble() == largeNumber.toDouble()` while `(largeNumber + smallNumber).toDouble() == Long.MAX_VALUE.toDouble()`.

Comment: I agree with everything you say, but my test still works. If you take your first expression without `BigDecimal` ( `Long.MAX_VALUE.toDouble() - Long.MAX_VALUE==0.0`), it gives true.  So my strategy still works, even if the internal representation is different.  And it doesn't matter if the `doubleVar-longVar` test is really `doubleVar - longVar.toDouble()`. A long overflow calculation  ends up being very different from a proper double calculation.

However, you are right, it's more ellegant encapsulate the check wiht exact functions.

Comment: See the edit for demonstration that your test fails (at least for addition).

Answer (score 1):

You should know that Long DataType has a fixed number of bytes [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> The long data type is a 64-bit signed two's complement
>   integer. It has a minimum value of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and a
>   maximum value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive). Use this data
>   type when you need a range of values wider than those provided by int.

```
//if it is not within the range then its an overflow (infinity/undefined)
if(a*b < Long.MIN_VALUE || a*b > Long.MAX_VALUE)
    println("Overflow")
else
    println("Ok")
```

**Edit**

Truly and unfortunately the above method is not reliable. See below table from a run test on android studio with JDK 8

```
##### Overflow Test #########

Long.MAX_VALUE     =  9223372036854775807
Long.MIN_VALUE     = -9223372036854775808

Long.MAX_VALUE - 2 = 9223372036854775805              
Long.MAX_VALUE - 1 = 9223372036854775806              
Long.MAX_VALUE - 0 = 9223372036854775807              
Long.MAX_VALUE + 0 = 9223372036854775807              
Long.MAX_VALUE + 1 = -9223372036854775808             
Long.MAX_VALUE + 2 = -9223372036854775807             
Long.MAX_VALUE * 2 = -2                               
Long.MAX_VALUE / 2 = 4611686018427387903              
Long.MIN_VALUE - 2 = 9223372036854775806              
Long.MIN_VALUE - 1 = 9223372036854775807              
Long.MIN_VALUE - 0 = -9223372036854775808             
Long.MIN_VALUE + 0 = -9223372036854775808             
Long.MIN_VALUE + 1 = -9223372036854775807             
Long.MIN_VALUE + 2 = -9223372036854775806             
Long.MIN_VALUE * 2 = 0                                
Long.MIN_VALUE / 2 = -4611686018427387904             
Long.MIN_VALUE + Long.MAX_VALUE = -1                  
Long.MAX_VALUE - Long.MIN_VALUE = -1                  
Long.MAX_VALUE * Long.MIN_VALUE = -9223372036854775808
Long.MAX_VALUE / Long.MIN_VALUE = 0                   
Long.MIN_VALUE / Long.MAX_VALUE = -1                  
Long.MAX_VALUE + Long.MAX_VALUE = -2                  
Long.MIN_VALUE + Long.MIN_VALUE = 0                   
Double.MAX_VALUE = 1.7976931348623157E308             
Double.MAX_VALUE * 2 = Infinity              
Double.MAX_VALUE + Double.MAX_VALUE = Infinity        
Long.MAX_VALUE * Double.MAX_VALUE = Infinity
Double.MAX_VALUE > Long.MAX_VALUE = true
Double.MIN_VALUE < Long.MIN_VALUE = true
```

Looking at the log you would notice anytime `Long.MAX_VALUE` reaches its peak instead of hitting Infinity like `Double.MAX_VALUE`, the bit is switched and its next value becomes `Long.MIN_VALUE` and it goes on and on like that.

So now we see why the above method isn't reliable. Hence we can assume that in java `Long is a DataType with zero Infinity`.

Method modified introducing floating point constants in-between

```
//using floating points forces larger memory allocation
//this prevents bit switch after crossing max or min value of Long
if(a * 1.0 * b < Long.MIN_VALUE || a * 1.0 * b > Long.MAX_VALUE)
   println("Either a Double or Long Overflow")
else
   println("Ok")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `Long` type doesn't work like `Double`. The result of a calculation does not give `infinity`, it simply operates inside the size in bytes and gives a result that seems somewhat unusual.

For instance, in [Kotlin Playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org) if you add `Long.MAX_VALUE` with `2L` the result is `-Long.MAX_VALUE`!